# Contact Form by WD disable captcha for custom page

Tags: wordpress, captcha

How to disable captcha for custom page, witch contain forms of plugin Contact Form by WD?

I tried to find hooks - I didn't find them, I tried to disable scripts - an error occurs, because the plugin writes the test result to the session.

Answer (score -1):

You can try modifying the plugin's behavior using custom code. Look for the plugin's functions that handle the captcha and form display. You may need to use WordPress hooks and filters to modify the behavior.

If disabling scripts causes errors due to the plugin relying on session data, consider using more targeted JavaScript modifications or finding alternative solutions like custom CSS to hide the captcha on the specific page.